# What is the difference between first and second -v flag syntax when using 'docker run'?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, docker

I am learning docker, as a sample I am running a simple react app.
To avoid building the image every time I change something in the source code I want to bind the local app directory with the container directory, and have ran into some issues.

When using:

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 -v $(pwd):/app node-test
```

to run the container I get the following output:

```
> react-app@0.1.0 start /app
> react-scripts start

sh: react-scripts: not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! react-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the react-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
```

and the container shuts down,
whilst using:

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 -v type=bind,source="$(pwd)",target=/app node-test
```

works perfectly fine and the react app is available on the port 3000.

What is the difference between one and another on a deeper level, that could cause this issue.

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14.16.0-alpine3.13
RUN addgroup app && adduser -S -G app app
USER app

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . . 

ENV API_URL=http://api.myapp.com/
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: Does the output of `pwd` contain any whitespace?

Comment: I'd say the two are the same and neither should work. The reason you're getting the error is that your volume mapping 'hides' everything in `/app` in the image, so that's why it can't find any node_modules. With a volume mapping, you're close to running a bare-bones `node` image as a lot of the things you do in the Dockerfile is done in `/app` and then not used when running the container.